# Entity Framework - Cannot insert the value NULL into column?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I have looked at all the similar questions on this topic but none seem to work for me. I don't know exactly why I am getting the below error when I try to run these two commands: `add-migration` and then `update-database`.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StudentId', table
>   'aspnet-JavaWebsiteProject-20171006053028.dbo.Groups'; column does not
>   allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been terminated.

I am using `Entity Framework v6.2.0`. I have three simple models below:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Teacher model:

```
public class Teacher
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

//Group model:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone guide me on what I might be doing wrong or how I can fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: is it initial migration or do you have already the tables in your data base?

Comment: it is initial migration - the very first one

Comment: try to dump you database and run: Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges

Comment: It's been a while since I've used migrations so I forget the exact mechanics, but is your migration creating initial seed data in the database? And if so, is that data defined completely for the Groups table?

Comment: @StefanW. Do you know what the problem could be, if I get this error when trying to alter already existing column's datatype?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the column to be nullable, you should set the property of your model to a nullable type.

```
public int? StudentId { get; set; }
```

After this, you will have to create and run your migrations again.

Answer (score 2):

Relating @StefanW.'s comment, if the Groups table already exists and you are adding the `StudentId` (and other) column(s) to it, if there are existing rows then those rows will have to have some value specified for each of the new columns. If you haven't specified a default value for the column then the database will attempt to use `NULL`, which will fail because the column does not allow null values.

Answer (score -1):

This question has been around for years. There are dozens of topics about it. In most topics, the answer is *"put IsIdentity=true and specify Identity start and step in the table design"*, or put your identity definition in SQL,

```
 CREATE TABLE ..
     [id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
     ...
```

like in

[Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080872/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-id-entity-framework)

.. and for some 75% of members, that answer works immediately ! But.. for the 25% it seems to be no solution. There are topics with an acknowledged answer, that suggest to *recreate* the table involved using migration commands (edmx context),

[Entity Framework Cannot insert the value NULL into column Identity Specification set to No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674086/entity-framework-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-identity-specification)

.. but I did not want to recreate my precious table, so that procedure was no option. Today I solved it here, *without* having to reset any tables. And the cause was *very* trivial. My connection string did not have a database addressed, so I actually scaffolded my tables in *another* database on the same server, where IDENTITY[1,1] was not set in Table create ! Of course, while debugging I checked only my own database :) , which was set correctly. But measures in table design had no effect. Of course not.. I was editing the wrong database !

To solve it, I changed my connection string to include initial catalog, from

```
 <add name="MyDBContext"  connectionString="Data Source=..;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=..;Password=.."  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to

```
 <add name="MyDBContext"  connectionString="Data Source=..;Persist Security Info=True;initial catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=..;Password=.."  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

One question remains.. why does Microsoft not *require* us to set the initial catalog for Framework 6 connection strings in app.config ? Above procedure could have destroyed an existing *other* database without notice..